# SQLAlchemy with Azure Synapse (SQL) - SAWarning: Could not fetch transaction isolation level

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-synapse

Trying to connect a SQL Synapse database with read-only access, Followed the advice re autocommit here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html

However receive the following error...

> SAWarning: Could not fetch transaction isolation level, tried views:
> ('sys.dm_exec_sessions', 'sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_sessions'); final
> error was: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]User does not have permission to perform this
> action. (6004) (SQLExecDirectW)')

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

conn_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" \
              "SERVER=mydatabase.database.windows.net;" \
              "DATABASE=somedbname;" \
              "AUTHENTICATION=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;" \
              "UID=gary@test.com;"

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": conn_string, "autocommit": "true"})
print(connection_url)

engine = create_engine(connection_url).execution_options(
    isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"
)

with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute("SELECT 1")
```

Must the read-only uses still require access to these views?

Comment: It's just a warning.

Comment: Yes fair point.